# Linear transformations.

Tags: linear-algebra

The isometry $f$ maps;

$(0,0) \rightarrow (3,-1)$

$(1,0) \rightarrow (3,-2)$

$(0,1) \rightarrow (4,-1)$

I am being asked to find the fixed point/points of this isometry
This is an affine transformation, therefore no points are fixed.
My reason for this post is the question is being asked and this paper doesnt involve any trick questions.

Comment: Affine trans. can have fixed points

Comment: nice, I added an answer below if you need..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to find the transformaition, and then to solve 2 linear equations.
The answer by the way is $(1,-2)$.